# How can I create an array from two models that have different keys in a Rails 3.2 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to combine the results of two tables into one array so that I can sort the array on the term alphabetically.

In my controller:

```
@defs = []

definitions = Definition.all
definitions.each do |d|
   ... # set the value of @term and @definition based on conditions
   @defs << {:term => @term, :definition => @definition}
end

definitions = Definition2.all
definitions.each do |d|
   ... # set the value of @term and @definition based on conditions
   @defs << {:term => @term, :definition => @definition}
end
```

Then I was hoping to display each item in the view:

```
@defs.each do |d|
   ...
   <%= d.term %>
   <%= d.definition %>
   ...
end
```

But I get the following error.

```
undefined method `definition' for #<Hash:0x007fb0cf109118>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be accessed as `d[:term]` and `d[:definition]`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your view is now working with an array of Hashes instead of ActiveRecord objects, you need to access the `term` and `definition` fields the same way you would any other hash value:

```
<%= d[:term] %>
<%= d[:definition] %>
```

Comment: Thanks Dylan. Wish I could accept more than one answer but biomancer was in first with the correct answer. Impressive reputation!

Comment: Actually, I think that Dylan was first to answer.

Comment: Right after i was notified, the time element said you 'answered 2 minutes ago' and Dylan 'answered 3 minutes ago'. If you insist, I'll change it to him.